Is there another possible option besides ScreenToWorldPoint?
Im trying to get a smooth camera to follow my mouse while also following my player character in a top down 3d environment.
This is my code and my camera is a Perspective one if that helps.
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CameraScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject Player;
    public float seeAbleDistance = 7.5f;
    public float speed = 0.3f;
    public Vector3 mouseDistance;
    [SerializeField] Vector3 curserPos;
    [SerializeField] Vector3 newCurserPos;
    [SerializeField] Vector3 playerPos;

void Update()
    {
        playerPos = Player.transform.position;

        mouseDistance = Input.mousePosition;
        mouseDistance.z = seeAbleDistance;
        curserPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(mouseDistance);
        
        newCurserPos.z = (speed * curserPos.z) + playerPos.z;
        newCurserPos.x = (speed * curserPos.x) + playerPos.x;
        
        newCurserPos.y = playerPos.y + seeAbleDistance;
        gameObject.transform.position = newCurserPos;
    }
}

my problem is that my newCurserPos will always rise exponentially with Player Movement.
is there a way to instead of having it be a screen to world point, have it be a screen to an gameObject's transform? and if so how would i do this? or is it possible to use ScreenToWorldPoint like how i want it to act and am i just stupid?

A camera cannot follow two things at the same time, think carefully about how to describe this position.

or is it possible to use ScreenToWorldPoint like how i want it to act and am i just stupid? .. well, how exactly do you want it to act? Im trying to get a smooth camera to follow my mouse while also following my player character is really not enough information to figure out what is supposed to happen exactly .. but from the code yes: if you do (speed * curserPos.z) + playerPos.z and the camera moves in that direction .. well then in the next frame you continue to move into that direction again etc ...

I think I understand the issue now:
As you move the cursor you also move the camera. In the next frame the camera has already moved in that direction so now you hit a world point that is even further in that direction and therefor move even faster in that direction.
What I would assume you want instead would be something like

Assume no movement if mouse is at screen center
Move faster in a direction the closer you get to screen edges
Limit the distance you can move around the player position

So I would probably rather do something like e.g.
[SerializeField] Camera camera;
[SerializeField] Transform player;
[Tooltip("Maximum horizontal distance the camera can move around the player")]
[SerializeField] float maxHorizontalDistance;
[Tooltip("Maximum speed the camera can move with (if cursor is at edge of screen)")]
[SerializeField] float maxMoveSpeed;

private Vector3 currentOffset;
private float yPosition;

private void Awake()
{
    // fallback if not assigned via Inspector
    // (Camera.main) is pretty expensive and limited to the one MainCamera
    if(!camera) camera = GetComponent<Camera>();

    // store initial Y position in order to re-apply again later
    yPosition = transform.position.y;
}

// in general it is usually better to do Camera movement after other Updates (for instance the player movement) have finished
private void LateUpdate()
{
    // 0,0 -> bottom left corner
    // 1,1 -> top right corner
    var viewportPoint = (Vector2)camera.ScreenToViewportPoint(Input.mousePosition);
    
    // map viewportPoint from ranges 0 to 1 into ranges -1 to 1
    // => 0,0 is screen center with no movement
    // -1,-1, is bottom left 
    // +1,+1 is top right
    var mappedInput = (viewportPoint - Vector2.one * 0.5f) * 2f;

    // convert from XY to XZ and apply multipliers
    var movement = maxMoveSpeed * Time.deltaTime * new Vector3(mappedInput.x, 0, mappedInput.y);

    // move the offset
    currentOffset += movement;
    
    // clamp to a maximum distance around player
    currentOffset = Vector3.ClampMagnitude(currentOffset, maxHorizontalDistance);
    
    // calculate and apply resulting position
    var playerPosition = player.position;
    var position = playerPosition + currentOffset;
    position.y = yPosition;
    transform.position = position;
}

Depends of course how exactly this should behave when the player is moving - currently it would just maintain the same offset.
